# How compiler is able to optimize the methods of class in internal namespace

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++

I have the following code which gets completely optimized by the compiler (g++-7)

```
$cat test.cpp
#include<iostream>
namespace {
class A {
public:
  void method();
  static void method1();
};

void A::method() {
  std::cout << "method";
}

void A::method1() {
  std::cout << "method1";
}

}

__attribute__((noinline))
A* foo() {
  A *a = new A;
  a->method();
  return a;
}
```

The assembly code does not have any functions. I'm confused because the function `foo` returns a pointer to `A` so compiler should know that `A` escapes this translation unit, or internal namespace disallows that?

```
g++-7 -O3 -S -o - test.cpp
LECIE1:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB2026-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE2026-LFB2026
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB2026
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x8
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .mod_init_func
    .align 3
    .quad   __GLOBAL__sub_I_test.cpp
    .constructor
    .destructor
    .align 1
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Pointer to `A` can not be used anywhere outside this translation unit as you can't name it. How would you get the name of `A` in translation unit bar.cpp so you can use/declare it?  If you move the declaration of `A` into a header file then you would get `anon1::A` and `anon2::A` in respectively each translation unit, ie diffferent `A`s

Comment: But i can assign it to void*?

Comment: @A.K.: to assign the return value from `foo` to some `void *` you must first declare the way to call function `foo`. How will you declare `foo` in some other translation unit? Or will do you this assignment in *this* translation unit? In which case, where is the function in which you do this assignment?

Comment: `class A; extern A*foo();`

Comment: @A.K.: If you put those two declarations into `main.cpp`, they refer to a *different* `class A`. The `class A` you just named is *your* `class A` in the global namespace in `main.cpp`. The `class A` in `test.cpp` is in an anonymous namespace. So, I repeat, how do you intend to name the `class A` that's in `test.cpp`?

Comment: @torek I can give the anonymous namespace a name `namespace xyz` and refer to `class A` as `namespace xyz { class A; }` in another file. But then the methods are not optimized anymore. Thanks for the explanation.